# How to convert HashMap<String,Integer> param to Map<String,Object)

Tags: dictionary, jasper-reports, hashmap, type-conversion

I want to call JasperFillManager.fillReport(filePath+".jasper", param, con); where param is supposed to accept type Map. is there any solution

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do, and what is not working? Have you created a `HashMap<String,Integer>` that you want to pass to `fillReport`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the constructor taking another map as an argument:

```
Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>(map);
```

See this example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("1", 1);
        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>(map);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `HashMap<String,Integer>` and you need to convert it to a `HashMap<String,Object>`, then the following should work:

```
HashMap<String, Object> objParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for (String key : intParams.keyValues()) {
    Integer intValue = intParams.get(key);
    objParams.put(key, intValue);
}
```

Where the `intParams` is your `HashMap<String,Integer>`.

There might be some typos in there as this is purely off the cuff.

Then you can pass the `objParams` to `fillReport`.

Comment: When iterating over a Map, consider iterating over the entrySet() instead of the keySet(). It is much more efficient as it does not requires the hashCode() and equals() methods of the key to be evaluate everytime to find the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the value type in HashMap, Java implicitly gives it a type of object.
In that case you just need to declare the original map as

HashMap objParams = new HashMap();

Answer (score 0):

Your .java file

```java
String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database";
String username="root";
String password="";
String database="database";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
JasperReport jc=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("F:\\pro\\report.jrxml"); //give your report.jrxml file path

//create hashmap to send data to report.key should same to report parameter
HashMap para = new HashMap();
para .put("name", "chamod");
para .put("email", "chamodck@gmail.com");

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jc,para,new JREmptyDataSource());
JasperViewer.viewReport(print);
con.close();
```

Your report.jrxml file text fields should be like this

```xml
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
```